# variable value in different methods

Tags: objective-c, variables

my problem is very simple (sorry my english, im speak spanish)

i have

```
NSString *ClaseUsuario;
```

AND

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *ClaseUsuario;
```

I have a method that changes the value of my variable

```
-(IBAction)setLabelEdad{
int val=(int)[botonEdad value];
if(val>0 && val<22){ClaseUsuario=@"C";}
if(val>=22 && val<35){ClaseUsuario=@"B";}
if(val>=35){ClaseUsuario=@"A";}

NSLog(ClaseUsuario);

}
```

but my problem is that when I call my variable from another method the answer is NULL

```
-(IBAction)VerOfertas{
NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Ofertas usario tipo: ",ClaseUsuario);   
}
```

I need to save the value assigned by the above method, please help! and thank you very much

Comment: Please log the following immediately before your other log statements: `NSLog(@"I am %@", self)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things to fix here:

Use a leading lowercase letter for your property: `claseUsuario`. This matters for KVC.

Do not declare an ivar at all. Just use

```
@syntheisze claseUsuario=_claseUsuario;
```

(Note the leading underscore. There is seldom reason to explicitly declare an instance variable any more unless you're writing for very old systems.)

Except in `init` and `dealloc`, always use the accessor. So this should be `self.claseUsuario = @"C";`. This will ensure that memory management works correctly.

Generally your `NSLog` should be of this form:

```
NSLog(@"Ofertas usario tipo: %@", self.claseUsuario);
```

Do not name your `IBAction` with a leading `set`. This can confuse KVC because it looks like an accessor.

The likely actual cause of your problem is that either `setLabelEdad` is never called, or you clear `claseUsuario` somewhere else, or you are looking at the wrong object. Put a breakpoint in `setLabelEdad` to test these.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much. do everything I say and not yet maintains the value of the variable.

Comment: You checked that the value is actually set, then isn't set, and that self is the same in both cases?